# Im getting this error when putting my HTML code into the W3C Validator: Quote " in attribute name

Tags: html

I am having trouble with my HTML code for my Introduction to HTML class. When I enter my code into the W3C validator, I get errors on the image's saying Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier. The only problem is that all the quotes match each other. I am not for sure where the error is at in my code. Can someone help me find it?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 960px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: #373737;
}

header {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: 500px;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: #373737;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #C0B283;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #C0B283;
  transition: letter-spacing 800ms, border-bottom 800ms, letter-spacing 800ms;
}

.studio {
  font-style: italic;
}

li,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  color: #373737;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

footer {
  font-size: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #373737;
  color: #C0B283;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2,
caption {
  font-size: 24pt;
}

mark {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #C0B283;
}

.ah {
  color: #373737;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #C0b283;
}

.vid {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background-color:#C0B283;
  height: 30%;
}

.img {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color:#DCD0C0;
  margin-top:3em;
}
.img2 {
  float: right;
  width: 49%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color:#DCD0C0;
  margin-top:14em;
}

.size1 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

.size2 {
 width: 70%;
 height: 40%;
}

video, video source {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}

.aud {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background-color:#C0B283;
  display:block;
  margin-top:10em;
}

video, video source, audio, audio source {
  margin:3%;
  float:right;
}

h6 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #373737;
  margin-top: -3em;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
 <header>
    <a class="ah" href="index.html"><mark>My Favorite Artist</mark></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="khalid.html">Khalid</a>
      <a href="dualipa.html">Dua Lipa</a>
      <a href="stromzy.html">Stormzy</a>
      <a href="postmalone.html">Post Malone</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
  <main>
    <h2><mark>Khalid</mark></h2>
    <div class="vid">
    <h3>Video</h3>
      <video controls="controls" poster="khalid.jpg">
        <source src="khalidvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="khalidvid.mp4" quality="high"  title="Khalid Better">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img class="size1" src="khalid2.jpg" alt="Khalid Free Spirit" height="200" width:"200" style="margin: 7%">
    </div>
    <div class="aud">
<h3>Audio</h3>
      <audio controls="controls" class="margin-left: 90%">
        <source src="khalidvid.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="img2">
      <img class="size2" src="khalid3.jpg" alt="Khalid American Teen" height="200" width:"200" style="margin: 2%">
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 25/4/2020<br>
      <small><a href="mailto:reed@wilson.com">reed@wilson.com</a></small><br>
      <a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="img2">
    <img class="size2" src="khalid3.jpg" alt="Khalid American Teen" height="200" width:"200" style="margin: 2%">
 </div>
```

Problem 1 is in above line it should be

```
width="200" not width:"200"
```

Same goes to

```
<div class="img">
  <img class="size1" src="khalid2.jpg" alt="Khalid Free Spirit" height="200" width:"200" style="margin: 7%">
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as the right answer, All the best

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a typo in this line

```
<img class="size1" src="khalid2.jpg" alt="Khalid Free Spirit" height="200" width:"200" style="margin: 7%">
```

You have `width:"200"` which should be `width="200"`